# UserControl bring Form to front

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way for a Custom `UserControl` to bring the Main Form of the application to the front?

*Basically I'm integrating with some 3rd party libraries that every time that I call them that application is brought in front of everything else.  I'm wanting to allow the custom control to request the main form bring itself back on top of everything.*

I had considered catching the `Leave` event from the main form, but this doesn't seem like it would be a good idea.

Program hierarchy...

`MainForm > TabControl > TabPages[] > each as a Custom UserControl`

I'd prefer to not have to make the parent or child aware of the other (unless that's the recommended practice).  My normal development is web based so who talks to who and proper design of a Windows Forms app is still new to me.

Comment: When this controls need to be brought to front? not b user-click I guess...so do they do some sort of calculation and when finished they need to be brought to front? I am sorry but I didn't got the idea you want to implement!

Comment: @Saeid87 I'm integrating with a Document Management System that we have On Site.  We currently are using a VBScript to automate a few tasks, but recently we have needed some functionality beyond what VBScript can provide (at least with the current developers we have (mainly me)) so I've been rewriting it to have that functionality inside of a C# Windows Forms app. The DMS takes focus whenever it performs a function.  I need the child form (the one that is aware it made a call) to be able to request focus again.  This is simply a usability feature for user so they don't have to click back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
Application.OpenForms[0].Activate() // or BringToFront()
```

But keep in mind, that you should have any opened forms, before you start your main form in `Main` method:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
// do not open any forms here
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

If you really need to have some forms opened before main form, then this will go:

```
Application.OpenForms["MainForm"].Activate()
```

Comment: Please modify answer to `Activate()`. `BringToFront()` does nothing (in my situation), but `Activate()` did and since your response led to the answer I'd like to give credit.

Comment: @Jared ok, changed :) but `BringToFront` should work, because `Activate` will only activate the form & give focus not necessarily bring in to front.

Comment: I'm not sure then.  I just tested it and it didn't bring focus back when I brought a browser on top of it.  The `Application.OpenForms[0]` is what I needed to get the `Activate()` function call back though so I'm happy and it's working!  Would you recommend a call to `BringToFront()` before/after as well?  As mentioned Windows Apps are not my first love when it comes to development...

Comment: Also was... *But keep in mind, that you should have any opened forms, before you start your main form in Main method:* just stating to make sure that MainForm was the first form created?  Wasn't really clear based on that sentence. (This shouldn't be an issue though since the app consists of `TabPages` and `UserControls`)

Comment: @Jared , you can create and open some form before you start main form of application. `Form2 form2 = new Form2(); form2.Show(); Application.Run(new MainForm());` In this case `OpenForms[0]` will return form2, thus it was opened before main form.